# How to find the factors of a number with for loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, logic

Hey I need some help with my AP Comp Sci homework. In the assignment I need to print the factors of a passed variable, z. This is what I've gotten so far in my method

```
public static void printFactors(int z) {
    for(int x=1; x<=z; x++) {
        if(z%x.......) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about finishing this? Or am I even on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: You should loop up to `sqrt(z)` instead of z.

Comment: for love of God, do your homework by yourself.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question, you want to get *ALL* factors, I might think, you want the full list, but distinct factors of an integer.

So, you can only iterates the integer x from 1 to `sqrt(z)`, but sqrt itself is too slow, and you can loop x until `x*x > z`, see the for loop below.

---

More, you should take care that if `z % x == 0`

for example: z = 18, x =3, z % x = 0

then z / x must be also a factor, too! It should be output.

but to avoid duplicated factors produced, if `z == x * x`, then `x == z / x`, the two factors `x` and `z/x` is duplicate, it should only be output once.

This is a classical algorithm issue, and this implemetation is the generally used one, which with time complexity `O(sqrt(z))`.

---

See the code:

```
public static void printFactors(int z) {
    for(int x=1; x * x <= z; x++) {
        if(z % x == 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
            if(x * x != z) System.out.println(z / x);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a try!

Comment: Thanks this seems to work! Can you help me understand what the last part means though?

Comment: @JeffSchaefer see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void printFactor( int z){
      for(int i = 1; i < sqrt(z); i++){
         if(z%i == 0){ system.out.println(i);}
      }
  }
```

The `== 0` is to make sure there is no remainder because the factor has to be an number with no decimal (of course)

The `sqrt` is because you would be checking the same numbers if you went passed that value.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to return anything, but I got it running. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSchaefer probably because of the brackets. I fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printFactors(int z) {
    for(int x=1; x * x <= z; x++) {
        if(z % x == 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
            if(x * x != z) System.out.println(z / x);
        }
    }
}
```