# Printing all factors of a number in Java?

Tags: java

How do I print a simple Java program that prints out all the factors of a number? For instance if the input is 12 the result would be *1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12*?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself first? If so, then could you share your code and specifically ask about the problem that you are facing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the factors of a number with for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799235/how-to-find-the-factors-of-a-number-with-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

You should use % function in java. It would be something like this.

```
for(int i = factor;i>0;i--)
{
  if(factor%i ==0)
    println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple way using Java 8 streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, factor).filter(n -> factor % n == 0).forEach(System.out::println)
```